# check input string has match given format laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, preg-match, string-comparison

Format of the string (x,y,z are the variables that will vary every time)

> ID:x Levely-z
>
> An example for the string will be ID:1 Level3-Super user
>
> x = 1
>
> y = 3
>
> z = Super user

Is there any methods not to use explode() recursively to check whether the input string has this format?

```
//check if missing 'ID' word on heading then return error
if(count(explode(" ",$string)) == 2){
    //check id
    if(count(explode(":",(explode(" ",$string)[0]))) == 2){
        id=explode(":",(explode(" ",$string)[0]))[1];
        //check the rest
        if(count(explode("-",explode(" ",$string)[1]))==2){
            $name=explode("-",$string)[1];
            //remove strings 'Level' to get the level number
            $level=mb_substr(explode("-",explode(" ",$string)[1])[0],2,2,"UTF-8");
         } else {
             array_push($error_msg,'Wrong format!');
         }
     } else {
         array_push($error_msg,'Wrong format!');
     }
} else {
    array_push($error_msg,'Wrong format!');
}
```

How do I use preg_match for this? All of the variables will have unknown length

Comment: What is x? When you ask a question make it as good as possible otherwise the answers will not be as good as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to check a string's format. For example, the following regex:

```
ID:[0-9] Level[0-9]-.*
```

Should match

```
ID:1 Level3-Super User
```

Comment: what about id and level more than one digit?

Comment: For two or more digits you can use `[0-9]+`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to go, using named groups:

```
$str = "ID:1 Level3-Super user";
if (preg_match('/^ID:(?<X>\d+)\h+Level(?<Y>\d+)-(?<Z>.+)$/', $str, $m)) {
    foreach (['X','Y','Z'] as $ind) {echo "$ind: ",$m[$ind],"\n";}
} else {
    echo 'no matches';
}
```

**Ouput:**

```
X: 1
Y: 3
Z: Super user
```

**Regex explain:**

```
/               # regex delimiter
  ^             # beginning of line
    ID:         # literally 
    (?<X>\d+)   # named group X, 1 or more digits
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    Level       # literally
    (?<Y>\d+)   # named goup Y, 1 or ore digits
    -           # an hyphen
    (?<Z>.+)    # named group Z, 1 or more any character but newline
  $             # end of line
/               # regex delimiter
```